# Problem with graphicspath and pdf_tex

Tags: graphics, input

I use `\input` for a subsection, in which I would like to include a pdf_tex file MK.pdf_tex via `\input`. The pdf_tex files are in a folder /fig. If I use `\input{./fig/MK.pdf_tex}` it returns the error "MK.pdf not found".

If I try to use the graphicspath as shown in the code below, I get the error "MK.pdf_tex" not found.

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{C:/Thesis/fig/}{./fig/}}
\begin{document}
\input{subsection}
\end{document}
```

And in my subsection:

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\def\svgwidth{8cm}
\input{MK.pdf_tex}  
\end{figure}
```

Thus, I assume that in the first case, only the pdf_tex gets the path information from input. In the second case I guess, that the graphicspath does not work.

If I put the MK files in the same folder as my subsection.tex, it works.

Thank you very much in advance,
Doedork

Answer (score 2):

The `\graphicspath{}` command defines the directories only for `\includegraphics{}`, therefore in the `\input` command you have to use the relative position, like `\input{./fig/MK.pdf_tex}`. If I remember correctly, there is the `\inputx` package that allows doing the same for `\input`; maybe you want to give it a try.

Comment: You remember incorrectly. `;-)` See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241828/define-path-for-packages-in-the-latex-file-analog-of-inputpath-or-graphicspa

Comment: @egreg Thanks, I didn't know that. I've found this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4602/how-to-make-the-main-file-recognize-relative-paths-used-in-the-imported-files/44215#44215. However, I could not make `inputx` work :-).