# Package grffile not working with graphicspath and filename containing spaces

Tags: spacing, graphics, directory

If the image is in the document's directory this works:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}

\begin{document}
    \input{"image name with spaces"}
\end{document}
```

If the image is in a sub directory called `images` this works:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./images/}}

\begin{document}
    \input{imagenamewithoutspaces}
\end{document}
```

But, again if the image is in a sub directory called `images`, this does not work:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\graphicspath{{./images/}}

\begin{document}
    \input{"image name with spaces"}
\end{document}
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there a limitation when using `grffile` with `graphicspath`?

**Edit**

The graphic I `input` is a `.pdf_tex`-file created by Inkscape's PDF+LaTeX export. I input the file by `\input{"image name with spaces.pdf_tex"}`. In this file `\includegraphics{image name with spaces.pdf}` is called.

Comment: \graphicspath don't work with \input, so your example  doesn't make sense.

Comment: Works as I described. But maybe the problem is more tricky than I expected (see my edit).

Comment: Where is `image name with spaces.pdf_tex`? (But I always wonder why people waste their life time to get file names with spaces working, when it is so easy to replace the spaces by something sensible.)

Comment: It is in the subdirectory `images`. (In my case it is because I want to support another application that automatically exports with spaces. Actually, I wonder why LaTeX does not support file names with spaces by default given that they are allowed in modern OSs.)

Comment: And why do you expect that latex can find it there? As I wrote: \graphicspath sets the search pathes for graphics, not for arbitray files. And I suggest that you read the documentation of grffile to understand some of the problems involved with spaces. It is imho a very bad feature of modern OS to allow them. It makes it very difficult to pass file names around in scripts.

Comment: I see. Sorry for my confusion. So I need to find a way to support spaces in file names with `import`. And this support is not by `grffile`.

Comment: Okay, so it seems I need to (1) specify the path explicitly in the `input` and embrace with quotes for the tex file, like `\input{"./images/image name with spaces.pdf_tex"}` and (2) add `\usepackage{grffile}` and
`\graphicspath{{./images/}}` to the preamble for the inclusion of the graphics that happens within the the file.

Comment: You are confusing search path problems and problems with spaces. `\input{"images/image name with spaces.pdf_tex"}` should work fine. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241828/define-path-for-packages-in-the-latex-file-analog-of-inputpath-or-graphicspa for a way to set search pathes for other files.

Comment: I see. Thanks. So LaTeX supports spaces in file names out of the box after all. Just the graphics input via `\includegraphics` is more tricky. My knowledge of LaTeX is very limited.