# Standalone with package in parent directory

Tags: standalone

I have three files, the files `main.tex` and `package.sty` located in the same folder and a `standalone` file `fig.tex` located in a subfolder `sub`, using a command from `package.sty`. The problem is that `standalone` says it cannot build `fig.pdf`. I use `standalone v1.1b`. I give the option `--shell-escape`.

- Am I doing something wrong?
- If not, is there a way to still use the
  `buildnew` option, with a setup where a `standalone`-file in a
  subdirectory uses a file in a parent-directory?

The file `main.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[mode=buildnew]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,package}
\begin{document}
    \includestandalone{sub/fig}
\end{document}
```

The file `package.sty`

```
\newcommand{\foo}{b}
```

The file `test.tex`

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{../package}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \node {$\foo$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Edit: One option seems to be to place a symbolic link to the package in the subfolder and then use the link. But this is not platform independent, and makes compilation more involved.

Comment: I don't think you can use `../` in a `\usepackage` path. However, without a link, can't you put simply your preamble in the same folder as the standalone input, and use `\usepackage{<standalone-subfile-folder>/package}` in your main and simply `\usepackage{package}` in the standalone ?

Comment: Also possibly related : [Define path for packages in the LaTeX file (analog of \input@path or \graphicspath for \usepackage)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241828/define-path-for-packages-in-the-latex-file-analog-of-inputpath-or-graphicspa)

Comment: [Here](https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/standalone/issues/24/including-standalone-class-files-in) the same question was posed. The answer is that the `latex`-run for the figure is not allowed to create files in the parent folder. Solution would be to let the files be created in the figures directory. There supposedly is an `build` option for that, to which you can pass `latex` compiler options. However, currently I do not get it to work.

Comment: @marsupilam Thanks for your comment. That works as long as all files using `package` are in the same folder. Also, it makes the file structure somewhat confusing.

Comment: Agreed, that would certainly be sub-optimal (but that's because of the constraint of no links !). Maybe you could make a proxy preamble file in your main folder, simply containing `\usepackage{subfolder/package}` to hide a bit this unpleasant involvment.

Comment: You shouldn't have **any** path in the argument of `\usepackage{}` as I understand it. Whether above or below the current directory. You can add to `TEXINPUTS` to get TeX to look in an additional place, however.

Comment: @cfr but this is a shell variable, no ? (I guess it can also be passed to TeX during compilation.) But what if we want to do all this using plain LaTeX files without compilation flags or shell variables, for portability ?

Comment: @cfr Perhaps you are right, that I should not use a path in `usepackage`, but still it works. I mean, the file `fig.tex` figure with `\usepackage{../foo}` is compiled correctly. It does not work with nested compilation calls. Anyway, your suggestion with `TEXINPUTS` seems to work nicely. Thanks

Comment: @HeinrichOdy My understanding is that it just *happens* to work and that this may be regarded as unfortunate. Hence, if it stops working, it will not be a bug as it is not designed to work in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

The following approach seems natural in `latex` and also works on a per project way, i.e. when each project requires different packages or is in a different repository.

- Create a directory structure `texmf/tex/latex/` directory
- Let the environment variable `TEXMFHOME` point to `texmf`, e.g. via `export TEXMFHOME=<path-to-the-new-texmf-dir>`. This puts `texmf` into the compilers search path. The subdirectories `tex/latex` are needed because the compiler expects files with different file endings in different places
- Move `package.sty` to `texmf/tex/latex/`
- Now,  you can use `\usepackage{package}` in `sub/fig.tex` and in `main.tex` and the file is found